# Jquery error in console

Tags: jquery

Am trying to concat

```
         var id = this.id;
         var repoCopy = repo.filter( "#" + id ).clone();
```

But when I run my code I have this error in console although I have used this before without facing any errors

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.compile (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa.matches (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.n.filter (jquery.min.js:2)
    at z (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.filter (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (index.html:527)
```

Comment: Maybe `id` is undefined (or null), and you're passing just `#` as selector.

Comment: it isn't .. if it is undefined it will show this console error instead 
Uncaught ReferenceError: id is not defined
@mrlew

Comment: actually, this is incorrect. As you're getting `id` from `this`, if `id` is not found (not a key from `this`), `this.id` will be `undefined`. Won't throw an error. Can be null or blank, also. Please, just for check, add a `console.log('id: ' + id);` before this line and check the output.

Comment: thank you @mrlew .. this solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `this`, if it's not what you think it is it might not have an id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
var id = "#" + this.id;
var repoCopy = repo.filter(id).clone();
```